# batch file for command parsing path

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to read a file path into a Windows Batch file variable

```
set print_nodePath=reg query "hklm\software\node.js" /v InstallPath
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3" %%a in ('%print_nodePath%') do set nodePath=%%a
echo %nodePath%
```

the reg query correctly returns

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\node.js

InstallPath    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

but I don't know how to write the 'for' command to grab the file path since it contains a space (C:\Program). I suppose I need to join the 3rd and 4th tokens?

is there a "good" way to write this?

Comment: Enclose it in doublequotes(_"_): `for /f "skip=2 tokens=3" %%a in ('"%print_nodePath%"')`.

Comment: @CristiFati, the command line parsed by the `for /F` loop executes properly, the issue is limited to the parsing only...

Comment: Thx, it seems that I didn't carefully read the question. Again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only a few modification:

- change `tokens=3` to `tokens=2*`;
- read variable `%%b` rather than `%%a`;

Here is the fixed code:

```
set print_nodePath=reg query "hklm\software\node.js" /v InstallPath
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2*" %%a in ('%print_nodePath%') do set "nodePath=%%b"
echo(%nodePath%
```

This works only if the registry value name does not contain white-spaces on its own.

Comment: thanks. I didn't know how to set the 'tokens' properly.